# iOS CG dashed double line path

Tags: ios, path, core-graphics

I want draw underground way symbol on map.

Actually the same path is drawed two times.
first with:CGContextSetLineDash(ctx, 0, lengths, cnt);

[image]

and second, no dashed, more tiny as first

[image]

result is:

[image]

Question is: how to draw double line as one path (not two with offset), dashed, transparent in middle?

[image]

Comment: The simplest way is to render a simple path twice, once a little wider with dashing, and again to hide the middle. You could also do it with either (a) a very complicated bezier path that traces these outlines; or (b) something that draws the dashed fat path and then something else that masks away the middle. But these are both far more complicated than the simple "stroke the path twice" tricks, IMHO.

Comment: Summary I draw two tiny dashed paths. Offsets in every node from middle main invisible path are depend from angle (rotated point). It works, but I think about something faster.